# Does not send Putmail messages via TLS

Tags: apache-nifi

I am sending a message using the PutMail [nifi] processor without using tls connections are sent. After setting the true SMTP STARTTLS flag, the processor crashes with an error.

Screen error

[image: 1]

The paths to the certificates that nifi uses are configured there are all the necessary ones that the server uses. I also added a certificate to the jdk in cacerts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to check certificates (client-server). (java/jre/lib/security/cacerts)
2. Need to use appropriate socket class, for example:

import com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory

MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory()

Comment: You are answering your own question, but from your answer it is not clear: 1) whether you have fully resolved your issue, 2) what was your issue, and 3) how did you resolve it. Please be more explicit in your questions and answers so that they can be useful for other users too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).